# Cambiar tamaño de Container dependiendo del tamaño del Child flutter

Tags: flutter

Estoy creando una aplicacion y necesito poner un texto, que en ocasiones puede ser largo y en otras ocasiones puede ser mas corto, necesito modificar dinamicamente el tamaño del contenedor de este text, algo asi como un boton de "ver mas" o  "ver menos", he visto varias cosas y las he probado, pero no me resulta en la practica, porque ademas de eso, el texto esta en medio de otro dos elementos entonces quisiera saber como hacer esa moficcacion de tamaño de manera dinamica.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: sin querer repetiste la pregunta, quita una ;)

Comment: de verdad??, donde??

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401382/ y https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401383/

Comment: 1) Está duplicada tu pregunta. 2) en la que elijas dejar, tienes que añadir más información. Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cambiar tamaño de Container dependiendo del tamaño del Child flutter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401382/cambiar-tama%c3%b1o-de-container-dependiendo-del-tama%c3%b1o-del-child-flutter)